# On an infinitely differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives, real-numbers

If $f$ is an infinitely differentiable function on $(0,1)$ with finite number of zeros in $(0,1)$ then prove that $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx=\log f(1)-\log f(0)$$

Since $f$ is infinitely differentiable with finite number of zeros in $(0,1)$, so let the zeros be $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$

So we get $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx=\left(\int_{0}^{x_1}+ \int_{x_1}^{x_2}+  \int_{x_2}^{x_3}+...+ \int_{x_n}^{1}\right)  \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} dx   $$
Now since $f(x)\neq 0$ and $f'(x)/f(x)$ is continuous in each of the above subintervals can we use the Fundamental theorem of calculus on each of the above subintervals?

Please give me some hint. Thank you.

Comment: The integral is not even defined if $f$ has zeros.

Comment: @MartinR Then what extra conditions do we need so that the integral is defined?